# Assign few connections from a connection pool to each specific task

Tags: java

I have a connection pool with 50 connections.

I want to dedicate

- 10 among these to task A
- 20 for task B

Is this a good practice? Is this possible in java while creating connection pools or thread pools?

Comment: Why not just creating two dedicated connection pools?

Comment: Indeed, two separate pools would be the logical solution to this. Anything else would be plain stupid. However this still leaves the question "is it a good idea to do this at all?". Are you trying to avoid starvation? How likely is it? What does your system do? Also, 50 connections sounds a bit on the high side.

Comment: Yes I am trying to avoid starvation. I don't want all the connections from the pool is exhausted by one task. 50 connections is just a dummy number

Answer (score 0):

Sharing resources between different participants is a good practice.

It is also a well-established practice to not do that *blindly*, but in context of priorities/goals/policies. Very often that happens on a higher level (think of load balancing); but of course, you could also built that **into** your application directly.

But to my knowledge, there are no simple mechanism in the (standard) java libraries to do that.

Long story short: if you want to use something like this; then you might have to step back and implement your own solution. In other words: you create your own connection pool that knows about "different" tasks; and that allows you to give priorities to them; and then the pool decides on such policies who will be served next.

On the downside: implementing something like this can turn out pretty complicated pretty quickly. Thus my first advise: go for two independent pools; make experiments and see how things work out for you. Only when you find that this solution is too inefficient for you; then start looking into your building your "load balancing"!